# How to draw a tree structure? (A two-dimensional space allocation tree recursion algorithm?)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graphics, tree, visualization

I have an arbitrary tree structure of nodes. I want to draw this tree to provide users a visual representation. I need to recurse over the tree and for each node add a graphic item to a list, and then just draw the list of items once tree recursion has finished. The recursion and drawing of items is of course trivial - what's a bit more complicated is  how to position the graphic nodes so they do not overlap with other branches.

I'm using Android but that is not important - I'm looking for an approach, possibly an algorithm that can maintain a picture of 2D space as it passes over the tree so it just allocates the most appropriate coordinates for each node as it makes the pass.

Any ideas?

**Update**

[This is the article with the best and most complete algorithm.](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/spe.713/abstract)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try the Walker algorithm.  [Here's an academic paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.16.8757) on the algorithm.  If you want code to look at, look at the [NodeLinkTreeLayout](http://prefuse.org/doc/api/prefuse/action/layout/graph/NodeLinkTreeLayout.html) in [Prefuse](http://prefuse.org/).  Prefuse is open source so there shouldn't be any problems adapting the code to your situation as long as you follow the terms of the license.

Comment: in the end i used a version of Walker's by Buchhiem. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I suggest drawing the tree linewise. You do this by using some kind of moving "drawing cursor".

You could store an attribute `width` for each node which is calculated as follows:

- the `width` of a leave is 1
- the `width` of an inner node is the sum of all childrens' `width`s

Then, you draw the root "in the first line" in the middle, which means, you just take root's `width`'s half.

Then, you generate a grid over the image such that each gridline corresponds to one line resp. one step from left to right and each intersection of grid lines can contain a node and each node has enough space.

Then, you iterate through the childs and while iterating, you accumulate the children's `width`s and draw the children "in the next line". To draw `currentChild`, you move your drawing cursor `currentWidth/2` to the right, draw `currentChild`, and move the drawing cursor the remaining `currentWidth/2` to the right.

In order to get the nodes in a good order, you might consider a breadth first search.

I hope my explanation is clear, but I think it will be better, if I draw a little picture.

This is our tree (`x` are nodes, everything else edges)

```
   +-------x--+-------+
   |          |       |
 +-x-+     +-+x+-+  +-x-+
 |   |     | | | |  | | |
 x   x     x x x x  x x x
```

So, you calculate the leaf's `width`s:

```
   +-------x--+-------+
   |          |       |
 +-x-+     +-+x+-+  +-x-+
 |   |     | | | |  | | |
 1   1     1 1 1 1  1 1 1
```

Then, bottom up, the `width`s as sums of childrens' `width`s:

```
   +-------9--+-------+
   |          |       |
 +-2-+     +-+4+-+  +-3-+
 |   |     | | | |  | | |
 1   1     1 1 1 1  1 1 1
```

So, you start at the root (`width` 9) and go 4.5 steps to the rigt in the first line.

Then, you move your "drawing cursor" to the second line, "column 0" (go to left).

The first child has `width` 2, so we go `2/2=1` grid lines to the right and draw the node and move the drawing cursor the remaining 1 grid lines to the right in order to finish the node. So, the next node has `width` 4, which means, that we go right 4/2=2 grid lines, draw, go the remaining 2 steps, and so on.

And so on with the next line. At the end (or in intermediate steps), connect the nodes.

This procedure ensures that there are no overlapping nodes (if grid lines are far enough from each other), but it might lead to quite large tree diagrams that could use the space more efficiently.

In order to detect unused space, one might just scan the lines after the above process and look if there are unused grid line intersections and then possibly realign some nodes in order to fill space.

Comment: this is what i came up with, though it gets complicated where branches are multi-levelled and you have to recurse all the way to the bottom of all of them before you can determine how they interact with each other. thanks for the answer, much appreciated.

Comment: what happens if the bottom leaf is in the right-most part of the tree? As in your example, if there was another child to one of the nodes of width 1 - then the node would be drawn to the left, right? I mean, it would have width 1, so 1/2 = .5 and it would be placed in the left part of the tree... which would be wrong. How would your algorithm handle that case?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Dot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_language). You can convert your tree to the dot representation and then using **Graphviz** visualize in any format you like. For example **Doxygen** uses it to represent the structure of program.

Comment: Thanks, though Grpahviz isn't going to work on Android, so it doesn't really help that much :(

Comment: @flesh, you said "I'm using Android but that is not important". Now you say if it doesn't work on Anroid it doesn't really help that much?

Comment: LarsH - I said it's not important because I was looking for a theoretical approach or an algorithm, rather than a library. You suggested a library, or at least a language that requires a library to parse it, none of whch appear to work on Android. I appreciate your suggestion though :)

Answer (score 2):

Graphviz and mfgraph are powerful, but they're for general graphs and are probably overkill for trees.

Try googling on tree+layout+algorithm or see [Graphic Javascript Tree with Layout](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/graphic_javascript_tree.aspx).
The latter is old but it uses HTML canvas and javascript, and it explains the code, so both the code and the approach should be portable.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the nature of your data, a [TreeMap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping) may be more appropriate than a tinkertoy representation.